# Não estou conseguindo apagar o índice referente ao cliente com JavaScript (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, tabela-html

Tenho uma tabela com diversas colunas, formados através de um array com diversas posições (em média 50 clientes), preciso apagar o resultado de acordo com a condição do cliente, **se o cliente estiver como PENDENTE ele sai da tabela (sai do array).**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**link da img:** http://ap.imagensbrasil.org/images/2017/03/15/pendente-01.png

Estou populando a tabela com NG-REPEAT utilizando o angularjs ex: {{ item.nome }}, sei que devo aplicar a regra no meu Controller principal para que o método (função) fique visivel em toda aplicação podendo ser reutilizado.

**Pergunta:** Preciso de uma regra (função) que desabilite ou apague todos os resultados que estejam como: PENDENTE referente ao cliente, como visto na img, lembrando que não adianta apagar somente uma variável preciso apagar o índice referente ao cliente que encontra-se como PENDENTE.

Não estou conseguindo apagar o índice referente ao cliente.

alguém tem uma solução, alguém pode me ajudar? obrigado!!

Answer (score 0):

Você tem 3 opções,

- Faça uma pesquisa no banco ja excluindo os itens pendentes.
- Rode o foreach criando uma outra lista e excluindo os itens pendentes da nova      lista
- insira na div do item do ng-repeat o atributo ng-if="item.documento !== "Pendente de envio"

Answer (score 0):

Então, sou iniciante em angularjs, o resultado da tabela é gerado quando utilizo uma função para detalhar os clientes, essa função utiliza uma resposta (array) dentro de um FOR (gera um loop com a lista de clientes), dai utilizo essa resposta para popular a tabela através do data-ng-repeat, até aqui a tabela retorna todos os clientes preciso restringir os clientes pendente de envio…

o problema é: eu não posso acessar o banco somente a variável que vem atraves de um array, tentei tratar com ng-if direto na tabela mas ele acaba sumindo com a coluna  (nao sei se apliquei no local correto), acredito que uma das formas de fazer esse tratamento seria quando chamo a função p/ filtrar os clientes, confesso que não estou conseguindo fazer isso…

apliqui o ng-if na DIV ferrou a rederização, to vendo o erro no console (firebug) (Error: [$parse:ueoe] Unexpected end of expression: item.estadoAtualCliente !==)

acredito que tenho que aplicar quando chamo a função que detalha os clientes, dentro da funçao que detalha os clientes tenho dois FOR, cada um faz um tratamento no final tenho um array com a lista total de clientes, essa parte que não to conseguindo visualizar como ficaria… será que daria certo criar um terceiro tratamento dentro desse loop??

(eu acho que…) uma boa pratica seria fazer esse tratamento fora do FOR para facilitar a manutenção, tentei fazer assim mas não consegui finalizar…

```
self.filtrarSituacao = function(estadoAtualCliente){
        return self.filtroSituacaoCliente.filter (function filtrar                      (estadoAtualCliente){
        return filtroSituacaoCliente !== ('Pendente de Envio');
        });
```

ps: demorei p responder porque estava testando as possibilidades aqui, vo dar uma lida melhor no foreach

Answer (score 0):

Você já tentou usar o [**ng-if**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) (também pode ser usado o ng-show ou ng-hide)?

Os seus links estão bloqueados para mim, então eu vou mostrar um exemplo.

E.g.:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope){
    $scope.records = [
        {
            "nome" : "Alfreds Futterkiste",
            "pais" : "Alemanha"
        },{
            "nome" : "Berglunds snabbköp",
            "pais" : "Suecia"
        },{
            "nome" : "Centro comercial Moctezuma",
            "pais" : "Mexico"
        },{
            "nome" : "Ernst Handel",
            "pais" : "Austria"
        }
    ]
});

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="valor in records">
        <div ng-if="valor.pais !== 'Austria'">{{valor.nome}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[***FIDDLE***](https://jsfiddle.net/gow3pLd4/9/)